# Form not submitting in GrapeJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, grapejs

I am working on custom landing page builder and for that I am using Grape.js, I have added form plugin and there is an input for endpoint and Action.

Users will mostly add a contact us form.

But when the user clicks on the submit button no request is going?

Users can either use forms or use input fields with a button.

I searched in the documentation but did not find any proper solution.